# Passar array de objetos via javascript para o controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, controller

Como posso passar um array de objetos do javascript para o controller?

**JQUERY**

```
var array = [];
var $linhas = $("#vendaTabela tbody > tr");
$linhas.each(function () {
   var x = {
    id: $(".codigo",this).text(),
    quantidade: $(".quantidade",this).text(),
    preco: $(".preco",this).text(),
    desconto: $(".desconto",this).text()
           }
    array.push(x);
        })

myJSRoutes.---.ajax({
            success: function () {
                $.smallBox({
                    title: "Documento adicionado com sucesso.",
                    content: "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i></i>",
                    color: "#C46A69",
                    iconSmall: "fa fa-check fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                    timeout: 4000
                });
            },
            data: {
                exemplo: JSON.stringify(array)
            }
        });
```

**CONTROLLER**

LINGUAGEM: Java

Da maneira que estou a passar, do lado do Controller recebo uma string com os objetos todos juntos. Como posso do lado do Controller ter acesso a cada um dos objetos do array?

Comment: Que linguagem tens no lado do servidor?

Comment: Qual linguagens do controller?

Comment: Desculpem por não ter mencionado. É Java !

Comment: no controller é JAVA ou JSP ?

Comment: vc poderia salvar os dados javascript em cookies então no controller poderá resgatar os cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Estás a passar um JSON serializado para o controler então precisas de fazer parse dessa string.

No PHP será `json_decode()` em NodeJs é `JSON.parse()`. Em Java acho que tens de usar uma biblioteca externa. Dá uma olhada aqui (http://json.org/ - documentação sobre JSON), no final da página, para bibliotecas que fazem isso: http://json.org/

Numa [resposta so SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574482/decoding-json-string-in-java) sugerem esta função:

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String str[])
    {
        String jsonString = "{\"stat\": { \"sdr\": \"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\", \"rcv\": \"aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff\", \"time\": \"UTC in millis\", \"type\": 1, \"subt\": 1, \"argv\": [{\"type\": 1, \"val\":\"stackoverflow\"}]}}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONObject newJSON = jsonObject.getJSONObject("stat");
        System.out.println(newJSON.toString());
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(newJSON.toString());
        System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("rcv"));
       System.out.println(jsonObject.getJSONArray("argv"));
    }
}
```

Existe ainda [outra pergunta com bons links](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591098/2256325) (incluíndo o que eu juntei em cima).

Entretanto uma sugestão opcional para o teu JS, usando `.map()`:

```
var array = $("#vendaTabela tbody > tr").map(function () {
    return {
        id: $(".codigo", this).text(),
        quantidade: $(".quantidade", this).text(),
        preco: $(".preco", this).text(),
        desconto: $(".desconto", this).text()
    }
}).get();
```

Comment: E para que serve essa parte do JS ? Ou como posso usá-la do lado do java?

Comment: @HugoMachado a parte do JS é uma sugestão para otimizar o código que tens, opcional.

Comment: àh Ok ;) eu tenho dificuldade é mandar o array de objetos para o controller em java

Answer (score 1):

> Como posso do lado do Controller ter acesso a cada um dos objetos do array?

Para responder a sua pergunta, vamos analisar melhor a situação apresentada.

1. é declarada uma variável do tipo array denominada `array`
2. para cada linha encontrada em uma tabela, é adicionado um objeto no `array` no formato `{codigo: a, quantidade: b, preco: c: desconto: d}`
3. antes de enviar para o servidor, o `array` é transformado em uma **string** através do método [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

O passo 3 vai transformar seu array de objetos em uma **string** parecida com:

```
[
    {'codigo':1,'quantidade':19,'preco':'$8.54','desconto':21},
    {'codigo':2,'quantidade':31,'preco':'$8.46','desconto':2},
    {'codigo':3,'quantidade':14,'preco':'$8.96','desconto':5},
    {'codigo':4,'quantidade':5,'preco':'$5.37','desconto':18},
    {'codigo':5,'quantidade':7,'preco':'$8.87','desconto':2}
];
```

Essa é uma **string** que representa o **JSON** gerado pela sua lógica, e é exatamente o que está chegando no seu controller.

Com base nessa informações, podemos responder a sua pergunta de 2 formas:

1. você pode alterar a forma como você envia os dados para o servidor, para que os dados já cheguem no formato que o seu *controller* espera (independente do *framework* utilizado)
2. podemos tratar essa **string** e reconstruir os elementos no lado do back-end.

Existem vários *frameworks* que vão te auxiliar a trabalhar com **JSON** no **JAVA**. Recomendo a utilização de um dos *frameworks* a seguir: [`gson`](https://github.com/google/gson) e o [`jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

## Resolvendo o problema com o framework GSON

Crie uma classe que vai representar os seus objetos javascript no back-end:

```
public class ItemTabela {

    public Long codigo;

    public Long desconto;

    public String preco;

    public Long quantidade;

}
```

Como a **string** que estamos recebendo representa um **array**, vamos declarar um [`type`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) para indicar para o *framework* o tipo de retorno que esperamos:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ItemTabela>>() {}.getType();
```

Agora basta utilizar o método [`.fromJson(reader, type)`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.reflect.Type)) da classe `com.google.gson.Gson`:

```
String json = "[{'codigo':1,'quantidade':19,'preco':'$8.54','desconto':21},{'codigo':2,'quantidade':31,'preco':'$8.46','desconto':2},{'codigo':3,'quantidade':14,'preco':'$8.96','desconto':5},{'codigo':4,'quantidade':5,'preco':'$5.37','desconto':18},{'codigo':5,'quantidade':7,'preco':'$8.87','desconto':2}]";

Gson gson = new Gson();

List<ItemTabela> itens = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```